# Notepadqq: How to change toolbar icons

Tags: ubuntu, icons, toolbar, ubuntu-17.04

When I launch `notepadqq v1.0.1` normally (by clicking on it's icon from the launcher), I get the following screen:

[image]

And when I launch it from terminal using:

```
sudo notepadqq
```

I get the following:

[image]

Notice the different icons:

[image]

1- Why do the icons change when I start the app using `sudo`? Does it pull a different version of the app?

2- How to change the default icons to make like the icons that appear when I run using `sudo`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do the icons change...

When you use a program using sudo (as root) you are going to see whatever icons and theme settings the root account is configured to use.  Otherwise you will see the icons you have selected as your user.

2. How to change the default (users) icons to make them match the icons that appear when you use sudo...

Note that notepadqq is a Qt program, not a GTK program, and the icon settings you chose for GTK will not apply to Qt programs.  You want to change your users Qt icon theme to "Adwaita". That is the name of the specific icon set you are seeing when you run with sudo.  I don't know what distro you are using.  I am using Xubuntu.  In my case I had to run the following three commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install qt5ct qt5-style-plugins

export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct

qt5ct
```

This should launch a GUI Qt5 Settings window, and allow you to select an icon set for Qt programs.  Pick Adwaita, click apply, then restart Notepadqq.  While you have qt5ct open you should also choose gtk2 as your qt5 theme to have a uniform appearance across gtk and qt applications.  You can also set your font sizes here for Qt to make them match your GTK settings.

I also edited the already existing export line in "/etc/X11/Xsession.d/56xubuntu-session".  (After a reboot) this allowed me to launch the the new "Qt Settings" object that appeared in the Xubuntu Settings window.

I'm not sure why, when I set both GTK and Qt icons to Adwaita, I get such different icons with mouspepad as I do with notepadqq.  They must just use a different set of images within that icon theme.

[image: Example Image]